# List View Webparts not Displaying

Tags: 2013, list-view-web-part

I have two SharePoint List view webparts that are not displaying on my page.

I am using SharePoint 2013.

Please advice.

Comment: How is your access this page?

Comment: Have you changed the layout of the page or is it as is? Also, can you check to ensure if those webparts exits on the page by navigating to page URL and appending "?Contents=1" to the page URL?

Comment: Never mind, target audience was set on those two webparts.  Thanks for the answers though.